# Oracle DST Time Conversion Error ORA-01878

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a select statement where i am converting timezones

```
Select
from_tz(cast(DATE_TIME as timestamp), 'US/Eastern') at time zone 'UTC' DATE_TIME_UTC
From Table1
```

but for some rows i am getting error due to DST

```
ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
```

i want to write a query like

```
select 
if error then do something else do the time conversion from table1
```

Comment: What are the results of select * from v$version and SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file ?

Comment: select * from v$version ->
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
_____
SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file ->
timezlrg_14.dat 14 0

Comment: @abeeweeda Would it be possible to provide sample dataset by updating the question?

Comment: @Jåcob, these are some of the dates 03/11/2018 02:06
03/11/2018 02:08,
03/11/2018 02:21,
03/11/2018 02:48,
03/11/2018 02:06,
03/11/2018 02:33,

Comment: Those times are erroring because they do not represent valid times in that zone, becuase - as you know - of DST. The problem seems to be with your data, not with the code, really. So how were the dates originally populated, and what zone (region, or offset?) were they supposed to be at the point they were created? Not just for those - for all your data. All the times seem to be ambigous - even though times after 3am will convert, they may not be correct.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes that why i want to do something like if the error comes i want to add 4 hours to the date else if there is no error i want to let the code do the conversion, all the dates which are in the table are in US/Eastern time and if i convert any other date apart from the date which do not lie between 2 to 3 am on second sunday of march its alright but i guess few records are populated wrong maybe so i need to convert those records manually (adding 4 hours)

Comment: just a note that your timezone has to be higher than 20 for oracle 12.1... it is currently 14 and may affect TZ queries

Comment: But the point is - how do you know any of them are really US/Eastern? Those between 02:00 and 02:59 are obviously wrong, but then how do you know all (or any) of the others are right? (And you the reverse issue too - how do you know how to handle the times in the hour that's repeated when the clocks go back?) Are you sure the originals are actually US/Eastern rather than a fixed -05:00 offset?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes that's what i am saying let us say those records are wrong and because of that my conversion is getting failed, is there any way to handle those records like i said earlier if not able to covert simply add 4 else do the conversion,

Comment: So you aren't worried that you might be converting other values incorrectly, as long as they don't error? OK... Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @sandman i am not sure what that means, i am not an oracle developer i just mainly use select queries to get data from database for further use

Comment: @AlexPoole i am not converting other values wrong as i have other table where the time is in UTC and we have some conditions to match the records and everything is matching fine also if i add manually 4 hours to wrong records they are also matching correctly that's why i want to do that if else thing, also why those records are wrong and all i am  not sure ... Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: you need to speak to your DBA about this; more info at /ORACLE/products/12201/oracore/zoneinfo or similar structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're on 12c you can use the enhanced subquery factoring that provides to define a local function; that can attempt the conversion with US/Eastern, and fall back to -4:00 if that fails.

Using your sample data and a couple of extra rows that will convert anyway:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR TZD';

with
  function get_tstz(p_date in date) return timestamp with time zone is
    dst_exception exception;
    pragma exception_init(dst_exception, -1878);
  begin
    return from_tz(cast(p_date as timestamp), 'US/Eastern');
    exception
      when dst_exception then
        return from_tz(cast(p_date as timestamp), '-04:00');
  end get_tstz;
select date_time,
  get_tstz(date_time) as date_time_converted,
  get_tstz(date_time) at time zone 'UTC' as date_time_utc
from table1
/

DATE_TIME           DATE_TIME_CONVERTED                DATE_TIME_UTC              
------------------- ---------------------------------- ---------------------------
2018-03-11 01:59:00 2018-03-11 01:59:00 US/EASTERN EST 2018-03-11 06:59:00 UTC UTC
2018-03-11 02:06:00 2018-03-11 02:06:00 -04:00 -04:00  2018-03-11 06:06:00 UTC UTC
2018-03-11 02:08:00 2018-03-11 02:08:00 -04:00 -04:00  2018-03-11 06:08:00 UTC UTC
2018-03-11 02:21:00 2018-03-11 02:21:00 -04:00 -04:00  2018-03-11 06:21:00 UTC UTC
2018-03-11 02:48:00 2018-03-11 02:48:00 -04:00 -04:00  2018-03-11 06:48:00 UTC UTC
2018-03-11 02:06:00 2018-03-11 02:06:00 -04:00 -04:00  2018-03-11 06:06:00 UTC UTC
2018-03-11 02:33:00 2018-03-11 02:33:00 -04:00 -04:00  2018-03-11 06:33:00 UTC UTC
2018-03-11 03:00:00 2018-03-11 03:00:00 US/EASTERN EDT 2018-03-11 07:00:00 UTC UTC
```

I've adjusted my NLS settings so you can see the difference in the converted values, as either EST, EDT or a fixed -4:00.

---

As mentioend in comments, you're ignoring the underlying data issues, and it would be better to correct the data that you know is wrong - assuming you can be sure why it is wrong and therefore how it is safe to fix; or to confirm your assertion that the original data is all supposed to be US/Eastern.

Fundamentally, as some are clearly not really US/Eastern, it doesn't seem safe to trust any of the data. Without knowing how and why those specifc records have values you don't expect, you can't be sure that any other values are what you expect either. Whatever application, tool or process inserted those dates may have (and probably did) insert other times which look OK but are also not actually US/Eastern. The rest may all convert without error, but that doesn't mean the UTC times are necessarily representative.

You also have a secondary problem in that you don't know whether a date you have recorded as 2017-11-05 01:00:00 was originally 01:00 EST or 01:00 EDT, as that hour was repeated when summertime ended. Oracle will just choose for you though.

Comment: Hi Is there anyway I can directly do an update instead of a Select? I tried with Update, But I get below error, ```ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"```. Any idea how to update those records directly instead of just selecting them?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function and checks if its a valid timestamp with time zone and use that function in the where clause of your query as follows for example.

```
create table t(x varchar(100));

insert into t 
  select '21-FEB-2009 18:00:00'
    from dual
  union all  
  select '31-FEB-2009 18:00:00' /*Junk date here..*/
    from dual;

create or replace function fn_test(dt in varchar2)
return int
as
l_timestamp timestamp with time zone;
begin
   l_timestamp :=from_tz(to_timestamp(dt,'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss'), 'US/Eastern') at time zone 'UTC';
return 1;   
exception
 when others then    
    return null;
end;
/

select from_tz(to_timestamp(x,'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss'),'US/Eastern') at time zone 'UTC'
  from t
where fn_test(x) is not null
```

Comment: Thanks George, this function might work but as i am writing the query in Qlikview (its a reporting tool) not is sql developer, also i don't need to discard the error records, my requirement is if error add 4 hours to the date else do the conversion. also i only can run select statements as per my privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message for one of these two reasons:

Most likely: you are trying to convert a local time that does not exist for reasons of DST switch, e.g. '28-MAR-21 02:34' does not exist in Germany (timezone Berlin/Europe), because clocks jump from 1:59 AM to 3:00 AM during night. Solution: add one hour, UTC will then reflect the correct time.

Less likely: typo in timezone string: "Europe/ Berlin" or "Berlin/Europe" - both is wrong, correct is "Europe/Berlin" (pattern is Continent/City)